# Error using H2O (from Python 3.9.10) and XGBoost backend on MacOS (Monterey, Apple M1)

Tags: xgboost, h2o, apple-m1

I am currently trying to use H2O from Python, and I encounter some problems on my Mac OS with XGBoost.
It seems like H2O does not find it anywhere.

More precisely, the next simple snippet

```py
import pandas as pd
import h2o

data = [['2015-01-01', '2490.925806' , '-0.41'],
        ['2015-01-02', '2412.623113' , '-0.48'],
        ['2015-01-03', '2365.611276' , '-0.55']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["time", "base", "target"]).set_index("time", drop=True)

h2o.init(nthreads=-1)
estimator = h2o.estimators.H2OXGBoostEstimator()
training_frame = h2o.H2OFrame(df) 
estimator.train(["base"], "target", training_frame)
```

gives me the error :

```
H2OResponseError: Server error water.exceptions.H2ONotFoundArgumentException:
  Error: POST /3/ModelBuilders/xgboost not found
  Request: POST /3/ModelBuilders/xgboost
    data: {'training_frame': 'Key_Frame__upload_893634781f588299bbd20d51c98d43a9.hex', 'nfolds': '0', 'keep_cross_validation_models': 'True', 'keep_cross_validation_predictions': 'False', 'keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment': 'False', 'score_each_iteration': 'False', 'fold_assignment': 'auto', 'response_column': 'target', 'ignore_const_cols': 'True', 'stopping_rounds': '0', 'stopping_metric': 'auto', 'stopping_tolerance': '0.001', 'max_runtime_secs': '0.0', 'seed': '-1', 'distribution': 'auto', 'tweedie_power': '1.5', 'categorical_encoding': 'auto', 'quiet_mode': 'True', 'ntrees': '50', 'max_depth': '6', 'min_rows': '1.0', 'min_child_weight': '1.0', 'learn_rate': '0.3', 'eta': '0.3', 'sample_rate': '1.0', 'subsample': '1.0', 'col_sample_rate': '1.0', 'colsample_bylevel': '1.0', 'col_sample_rate_per_tree': '1.0', 'colsample_bytree': '1.0', 'colsample_bynode': '1.0', 'max_abs_leafnode_pred': '0.0', 'max_delta_step': '0.0', 'score_tree_interval': '0', 'min_split_improvement': '0.0', 'gamma': '0.0', 'nthread': '-1', 'build_tree_one_node': 'False', 'calibrate_model': 'False', 'max_bins': '256', 'max_leaves': '0', 'sample_type': 'uniform', 'normalize_type': 'tree', 'rate_drop': '0.0', 'one_drop': 'False', 'skip_drop': '0.0', 'tree_method': 'auto', 'grow_policy': 'depthwise', 'booster': 'gbtree', 'reg_lambda': '1.0', 'reg_alpha': '0.0', 'dmatrix_type': 'auto', 'backend': 'auto', 'gainslift_bins': '-1', 'auc_type': 'auto', 'scale_pos_weight': '1.0'}
```

For more information about my distribution:

- OS: Monterey 12.3
- Processor: Apple M1
- Python: 3.9.10
- H2O: 3.36.0.3

I suspect Apple M1 to be the cause of the error, but is that really the case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, the XGBoost is not supported on Apple M1 processor yet.

https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-8482