# h2o XGBoost unavailable on MacOS (Apple M1)

Tags: xgboost, apple-m1, h2o

When I run h2o AutoML in python on my MacOS with Apple M1 chip, I get a message "*XGBoost is not available; skipping it.*". I found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529386/error-using-h2o-from-python-3-9-10-and-xgboost-backend-on-macos-monterey-app) from more than a year ago. So I am wondering if there has been any progress (and therefore my issue has different causes), or XGBoost has still not been compiled for Apple M1.

Python: 3.9.2
h2o: 3.44.0.2
processor: Apple M1